# Laravel import javascript custom file with webpack mix

Tags: javascript, laravel, webpack

I'm trying to define javascript functions in my Laravel 5.4 project (with Laravel boilerplate).
I have a custom.js file with functions.

```
function displayDef(){
    $("#worddef").html("Yippee");
}
```

This file is included in the assets via webpack.mix.js and is properly found in the frontend.js after compilation.

**Problem:**

> the function is undefined:
>       Uncaught ReferenceError: displayDef is not defined

The function is present in the compiled js file:

```
 /* 36 */
    /***/ (function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {

    /* WEBPACK VAR INJECTION */(function($) {/* 
     * Local functions
     *
     */

    function displayDef() {
    ...
```

I've no idea how I'm supposed to access these functions.
Also if I try to put it in another file:

```
.js([
    'resources/assets/js/chinese.js'
], 'public/js/vendor.js')
```

I just get a second identical file.

I'm quite surprised there is no topic answered about that: how to properly define and access javascript functions in laravel 5.4 with mix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`js()` function in `mix` is used to compile the module bundled file.

**From Laravel site :**

```
mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js');
```

> With this single line of code, you may now take advantage of:
>
> - ES2015 syntax.
> - Modules
> - Compilation of .vue files.
> - Minification for production environments.

If this function is in legacy javascript, you can use `script` function to compile it.

> This option is particularly useful for legacy projects where you don't require Webpack compilation for your JavaScript.

For more check here : https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mix#working-with-scripts

Comment: This is already what I am doing. I get a 260kB js file out of my original 420B functions, and these 2 functions are not defined globally. How do I access them in my view?

Comment: Use `script` function instead `js`.

Comment: Thank you, it worked with a few details that aren't in the doc. However, I don't understand why this is a legacy way of doing things. What is the proper way of adding javascript to a project then?

Comment: @NicolasBernard can you explain?

Comment: mix.scripts('resources/assets/js/chinese.js', 'public/js/chinese.js'); I don't remember exactly that's a year ago @AlineMatos

Answer (score 0):

In your project root directory, run the update

```
    npm update
```